# Use HttpContext over threads by using DI (structuremap)

Tags: c#, asp.net, structuremap

I am trying to configure a class by using Structuremap so to use the Current HttpContext over threads as well.

I have this class

```
public class SiteContext
{
    public SiteContext(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        HttpContext = context;
    }

    public HttpContextBase HttpContext { get; private set; }
}
```

If I use the following in my BootStrapper Class, the system will throw an exception when attempts to get the HttpContext.Current. [The HttpContext is null]

```
For<SiteContext>()
            .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
            .Use(() => new SiteContext(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)));
```

whereas if I use the following, I can get the HttpContext.Current in contrast of the session where is null.

```
For<SiteContext>()
            .HttpContextScoped()
            .Use<SiteContext>()
            .Ctor<HttpContextBase>("context")
            .Is(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));
```

**EDIT**

```
For<HttpContextBase>()
            .HttpContextScoped()
            .Use(() => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));
```

is there a way that I can use the HttpContext.Current over threads?

I will appreciate any comment.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately not - threads have a different lifetime than a HttpContext and multiple threads can service multiple requests.  What is your dependency on HttpContext?

Comment: I guess the HttpContext should be passed to the thread upon start, be stored as a static member of a utility class, where your DI would be able to retrieve it. Beware of memory leaks though...

Comment: @drch thanks for your reply. I've edited my initial post with HttpContext dependency

Comment: @StrouMfios what I meant was what do you need HttpContext for?  Session?  User?  Cache?  There are different approaches for accessing or duplicating these outside of a request context.

Comment: I needed for Session, that's why I posted that the session is null but it isn't clearly mentioned in my initial post :)